# How can I get my pickup to persist between levels?

Tags: unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I have a light pack pickup for my player that I would like to not have to place in every level to pick up. I have a game instance with the variables, but I am drawing a blank on how to proceed.

I have tried setting the variables in both game instance and the player blueprint. I have tried casting to the player from the game instance and setting player variables to the game instance variables. And vice versa casting to the game instance inside of the player blueprint.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is good.

- Make a variable in your GameInstance (which need to be set in project settings)
- Make a variable in the Player (or other Actor, Pawn...)
- every time you want to save this variable (end of the level? On Pickup?) get the GameInstance -> cast it to your specific GameInstance and set the value.
- vice versa for loading the variable from game instance in the begin play event.

Alternatively you could save at the end of a level and load again on the next (https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/InteractiveExperiences/SaveGame/). This is maybe a more desired approach if the pickup should still be there even if the game is restarted.

Hope this helps.